# CSS fluid layout scaling content

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a CSS question you may be able to help with.

I'm trying to build a website with a 'Fluid' layout.

All website content will be contained within a wrapper div

When the screen shirks, I Would like the wrapper div to shirk along with it's content.

However, when the screen size is increased, I would like the wrapper div to maintain a max size. The aim is to prevent images scaling beyond their native resolution and the formatting of text changing (a paragraph may become a single line on very large screen)

Can I apply a max pixel with and a percentage to the wrapper DIV? is there a better way to achieve the goal?

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 1000px;
    }
```

Many thanks,
P

Comment: Use Media Queries...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this and it is a good practice.

Comment: ok thanks guys. I'm what does the 80% mean .... Does this mean it's 80% of 800px?

Comment: Thanks Arjun,  So its 80% of the browser window when it reaches below 800px?

Comment: @user2324730:check my answer

Answer (score 0):

> Can I apply a max pixel with and a percentage to the wrapper DIV?

**YES**, you can apply it

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 1000px;
    }
```

the `width: 80%;` means `80%` of the screen width(or browser window) and it will not exceed   `max-width: 800px;`

> The max-width property in CSS is used to set the maximum width of a
>   specified element. The max-width property overrides the width
>   property, but min-width will always override max-width whether
>   followed before or after width in your declaration.

Comment: Thanks Arjun and Sajad,  So its 80% of the browser window when it reaches below 800px?

Comment: @user2324730:yes,it will always take 80% of the browser window and not exceeding 800px

Comment: @user2324730:accept my answer if it gave you the answer

Comment: yes, it gave me the answer thanks it was very clear !... how does one accept?

Comment: @user2324730 click the green tick arrow left to my answer